# Pesquisa sql com data limite maior e menor

Tags: sql, query, datetime, data, return

Meu código deve retornar valores do banco de dados, relacionados ao dia atual (hoje), mas somente relacionados ao mês e dia, pesquisei muito mas não consegui encontrar algo que me ajudasse

```
$data_atual = date("d-m");
$mostraDados = mysqli_query($conecta,  "SELECT * FROM sql WHERE ativo = 's' AND inicio >= '".$data_atual."'")or die (mysqli_error());
```

na coluna `inicio` da tabela fica a data, como por exemplo `13-10`, então a linha de consulta deveria retornar tudo acima do dia 13 do mês 10, mas esta dando erro. No caso, a variável `$data_atual` pega o dia e mês do server para fazer a consulta e verificar com a coluna inicio.

Comment: Qual erro está retornando ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html use functions de data como year(0 , month() e now()

Comment: o erro é que nao retorna os valores @WéllingthonM.deSouza

Comment: @Motta , tinha esquecido da função NOW(), to pesquisando agora para ver se resolvo o codigo

Answer (score 1):

Você vai ter que usar função `DATE()` para converter as duas datas para o formato "aaaa-mm-dd" e compará-las. Então pra obter todos os registros da data de hoje, você teria a seguinte query:

```
SELECT * FROM sql WHERE ativo = 's' AND DATE(inicio) >= DATE(NOW())
```